# The max data files limit in mongodb collections？

Tags: mongodb

When I read the docs of mongodb I found that there is a limitation of the size of collections. `The MMAPv1 storage engine limits each database to no more than 16000 data files. This means that a single MMAPv1 database has a maximum size of 32TB.`. I don't know what `data files`, does this kind of data ( just as below) count as a data file? So can I insert more than 16000 data in one collection?

`{ "_id" : ObjectId("57159666b5492a881a2bb891"), "Status" : " incomplete ", "Add_Date" : " 2016-04-08 ", "Link" : "?id=Gp0138425", "Id" : "Gp0138425", "Name" : " Human skin bacterial and viral communities - University of Pennsylvania - MG100786 " }`

Answer (score 0):

The json data you have shown in typically knows as document in mongodb:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57159666b5492a881a2bb891"), "Status" : " incomplete ", "Add_Date" : " 2016-04-08 ", "Link" : "?id=Gp0138425", "Id" : "Gp0138425", "Name" : " Human skin bacterial and viral communities - University of Pennsylvania - MG100786 " }
```

You can store as many as such documents in a collection with the limits specified at [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.6/reference/limits/#Data-Size) docs.

Note that the each document is bound to limit 16MB.

Comment: So there is no quantity limitation, there is only the size limitation?

Comment: the size is subject to increase when you inserts documents in mongodb and is bound to an OS specific limit

Comment: Just like the document I've mentioned. Can I insert about 25 thousand them into one collection. If can't, what should I do to solve this?

Comment: Yes, you can insert 25 thousand such a documents into a collection.